# R Shiny - How to connect string and number to new string and print

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following problem: I want to write a shiny app that allows to enter a variable name (e.g. "test") and a number (e.g. "5") so that a vector of these variable names numerated from one to the input number ("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5") is displayed. But somehow it doesn't work.

server.r:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$varName<-renderUI({
      textInput("name", "Variable Name", value = "test")
  })

  output$number<-renderUI({
      numericInput("number", "Number", value = 5, min = 0, max = 10)
  })

  connect=reactive({
      name<-input$name
      n<-input$number
      var.names<-rep(name, n)
      var.names.n<-paste(var.names,seq(1:n),sep=",")
  })

  output$view <- renderPrint({
      connect()$var.names.n
  })

}
```

And ui.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Set Variable Names"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("varName"),
    uiOutput("number")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("view")
  )
))
```

Would be very greatful if someone could have a look at it :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure that `connect()` returns a value in all cases. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connect() return nothing

1) add return to connect reactive

2) edit render print

3) add check if inputs exists

4) add check if input$number more than 0

Example

```
connect=reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$name) & ! is.null(input$number) ){
      if(input$number>0){
      name<-input$name
      n<-input$number
      var.names<-rep(x=name, times=n)
      var.names.n<-paste(var.names,seq(1:n),sep="")
      return(var.names.n)
      }
    }
  })

  output$view <- renderPrint({

    connect()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Batanichek for the `is.null` condition check, this solved an initial error.

ui.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Set Variable Names"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("varName"),
    uiOutput("number")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("view")
  )
))
```

server.r:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$varName<-renderUI({
    textInput("varName", "Variable Name", value = "test")
  })

  output$number<-renderUI({
    # please note that an input value of 0 will cause a problem below.
    numericInput("number", "Number", value = 5, min = 0, max = 10)
  })

  connect<-reactive({

    if(!is.null(input$varName) && ! is.null(input$number) ){
    name<-input$varName
    n<-input$number
    var.names<-rep(name, n)
    var.names.n<-paste(var.names,seq(1:n),sep="")
    return (var.names.n)
    }
  })

  output$view <- renderPrint({
    connect()
  })

}
```

Comment: see result of input$number=0 or below ... ( `seq (1:0)==c(1,2)` )better add some explanation